# What does const T& value() const mean?

Tags: c++

In the book "Programming Interviews Exposed" by John Mongan ([see page 33](http://books.google.ca/books?id=GQE4r2e5fAsC&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=const%20T%26%20value%28%29%20const%20programming%20interviews%20exposed&source=bl&ots=_itXIwBEB_&sig=zsMKmssX2JlOJvy_3rweyTqY53E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fHJ2VLydIsvbsATkowI&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=const%20T%26%20value()%20const%20programming%20interviews%20exposed&f=false)), theres a function declaration for a Singly Linked List Element:

```
const T& value() const {...}
```

I understand what everything before the method name means, namely that it is a reference to a template datatype which you may not modify, but what does the extra const after the value() signify? A constant reference? I thought references were already constant (i.e. unchangeable alias which is the object).

Comment: References are not always constant, i.e. `const int&` is not the same as `int&`. In the first case, you can refer (alias) and `int` but cannot modify it, and can also bound the `const int&` to a temporary, whereas in the last case you refer (alias) an `int` and are able to change it. In the latter case, you CANNOT bind a temporary to a non-const reference, as C++ standard forbids you, unless you are using Microsoft's compiler, which has a way of cheating everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const T& value() const {...}
```

This means the function `value()` will return a `const T&` type and in between (in the function) won't modify the class itself.
Say I write:

```
class Cfoo
{
    void foo() const
    {
        //Cfoo will not be modified here
    }
}
```

If I directly quote from [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/const-cpp): 
**Declaring a member function with the const keyword specifies that the function is a "read-only" function that does not modify the object for which it is called. A constant member function cannot modify any non-static data members or call any member functions that aren't constant.**

Comment: So essentially this is saying that both the caller and callee cannot change the class members

Comment: The caller can't modify a private member anyway, but even a constant member function can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The `const` after the method name signifies that the method does not modify any field of the object.  Therefore, it can be invoked on a `const` instance of the object.

Comment: It can also be invoked on a non-const instance of the object; that's not quite the point.